# Xcode9 wireless debugging doesn't connect on the university network

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, ios11, xcode9

I've been trying to use wireless debugging on Xcode9 on the network as it'd be pretty useful to have for a project I'm working on, and it connects normally to my home network. However, when I try this on the university network to work on my project it doesn't seem to connect at all. I've tried resetting the Location & Privacy Settings on the iPad, resetting the Network Settings, unpairing the device, and restarting both the Mac and the iPad to no effect.

[No network connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4ndU.png)

I can confirm that both the iPad and the Mac are connected to the same university network.

Using:

macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (Macbook Pro)
XCode 9.0
iOS 11.0

Comment: Are devices on the network able to see each other? It's probably a security issue for them so you might be out of luck.

Comment: same issue I faced when I tried to connect to my office open Wi-Fi network. It works perfectly on  personal network

Answer (score 2):

There is one thing I tried when I had the similar problem as you have:

1) Try connecting to your iPhone or iPad by specifying its IP Address.

Let me know if that works for you.

[image: Xcode> Window> Devices and Simulators> Connect via IP address option]

Once, I was able to connect to my iPhone in the university network by doing that. But then I lost the connection after 20-30 minutes. After that, I was not able to connect with my device by using its IP address there. Maybe it has something to do with the network configuration as the network is public, but not sure.